# BodyParser is not parsing the required data

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Body parsing isn't passing any data when i use postman to make a request. When i use the console.log to view the req.body it gives an empty object.. Any ideas why this is happening

Thanks

```js
const app = require('express')();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/amazon';



mongoose.connect(uri, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to the DB');
})


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Hellow');
});

app.post('/create-user', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    let user = new User();

    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.email = req.body.email;

    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        res.json('Successfully created user ' + user.profile.name);
    })
})

app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('Server running');
});
```

Comment: Could you post the error log?

Comment: There was no error the req.body just return an empty field and in the mogodb it store the name as undefined

Comment: How do you call your /create-user then? Seems like the body is missing at all.

Comment: I used postman to call the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postman request should look similar to this image attached

[image: Sample]

Adding Content-Type : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" should resolve ur issue.

Comment: Interesting, how did you find this out without even having the request that was made?

Comment: I also had this problem some time back.